# Why is a parameter of bean in camel route the body value of exchange?

Tags: apache-camel

I am a starter for camel. I have a question. I have one route.

```
<route>
    <from uri="file:/test/inBox"/>
    <bean method="processingAuditInsert(*, 'RD', 'AA')" ref="fileAuditHandler"/>
    <bean method="processingAuditUpdate(*, 'IU')" ref="fileAuditHandler"/>
    <toD uri="file:/test/outBox"/>
    <bean method="processingAuditUpdate(*, 'CO')" ref="fileAuditHandler"/>
</route>
```

I applied each parameter for processingAuditUpdate method.
'IU' parameter is correct set to processingAuditUpdate method.
And during second calling method 'processingAuditUpdate', I want to set 'CO' value.
But after processing, this value is the body value of exchange.

I don't understand this situation.
Please help about this situation.

Thank you.

**fileAuditHandler.java**

```
@Handler
public void processingAuditUpdate(Exchange ex, String status) {
    if (status.equals("IU")) {
        // Update Status 'IU'
    } else (status.equals("CO")) {
        // Update Status 'CO'
    } else {
        log.error("Update Status value is invalid!!!! ::::: {}", status);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you would provide full code of FileAuditHandler

Comment: FileAuditHandler only acts insert and update in table of db. I wonder why the parameter is the value of body, not ‘CO’.